Involution of $\text{GL}_{m+n}(\mathbb{C})$ fixing Levi and exchanging parabolic subgroups
Is there any involution of $\text{GL}_{m+n}$ which is the identity on $\text{GL}_m\times\text{GL}_n\subset\text{GL}_{m+n}$ and that exchanges the positive and negative associated parabolic subgroups $P$ and $P^-$? I think it is not the Cartan involution, nor an inner automorphism: conjugating by and element of $\text{GL}_m\times\text{GL}_n$ does not exchange the parabolic subgroups, and conjugating by another element does not preserve the Levi... But I don't know if it could be a combination of both.
It could also be helpful if I find and involution $\sigma:\text{GL}_{m+n}\to\text{GL}_{m+n}$ exchanging $P$ and $P^-$ and such that twisting the natural representation $V$ of $\text{GL}_{m+n}$ by $\sigma$, we get a representation $V^\sigma$ isomorphic to $V$, even if it doesn't fix the Levi subgroup.

No. There is not even an isomorphism between $P$ and $P^-$ that is he identity on $GL_n \times GL_m$.
The Lie algebra of $P$, as a representation of $GL_n \times GL_m$, is the adjoint representation of $GL_n$ plus the adjoint representation of $GL_m$ plus the tensor product of the $n$-dimensional standard representation of $GL_n$ with the dual of the $m$-dimensional standard representation of $GL_m$.
The Lie algebra of $P^-$ is the adjoint representation of $GL_n$ plus the adjoint representation of $GL_m$ plus the tensor product of the dual of the $n$-dimensional standard representation of $GL_n$ with the $m$-dimensional standard representation of $GL_m$.
These Lie algebras are not isomorphic as representations of $GL_n \times GL_m$, so the groups cannot be isomorphic in a $GL_n \times GL_m$-respecting way either.
If $m=n$ then your other question has a positive answer, given by conjugation by a block matrix of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & I_n \\ I_n & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. The condition that $V^\sigma$ is isomorphic to $V$ is exactly the condition that $\sigma$ is an inner automorphism, and an inner automorphism switching the two exists if and only if $m=n$.
